# Convert @select variable to object or simple variable or remove AnonymousSubject

Tags: angular

I'm using Redux architecture in Angular. I'm getting the state's value in the component using `@select` (select pattern). However while printing the `@select` variable using console I'm getting the below output as AnonymousSubject

> AnonymousSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}

Below is the code to fetch the state from store,

```
@select(state => state.ProductList) products;
```

How to convert **products** into simple array or let me using the same statement can I console the **products** where I can see my array elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select something using @select from a redux store you didn't get value,instead you will get an observable and you should subscribe that.

```
@select(state => state.ProductList) products$: Observable<any>;
protected productsSubscription : Subscription;

 ngOnInit() {
    if (this.productsSubscription == null) {
      this.productsSubscription = this.products$.subscribe(d => {
       // Enter here when observable filled/updated values
       // your code should be here
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the solution, it worked. However I have one doubt here. Why do need to check null for the subscription?